# Xamarin Design Issue in landscape mode

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to design a screen in `Xamarin.Forms` that having `Image` as background on screen and main content `StackLayout` having white background in center of main screen. For that I've tried this yet:

```
<RelativeLayout x:Name="mainContainer" >
   <Image Source="bg.png" Aspect="Fill"
               RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
               RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
   <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"  >
     <StackLayout Padding="100,100,100,100">
         <StackLayout x:Name="MainContent" backgroundcolor="white">
         </StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm giving padding here so my content can come in center. But that padding will be different when i run in landscape mode. So what could i do instead to just make content `StackLayout` in center of the screen ?any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Grid` instead `RelativeLayout`

```
<Grid>
  <Image Source="bg.png" Aspect="Fill"/>
  <StackLayout x:Name="MainContent" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="100">
    <!--Your content goes here-->
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: that will do same thing.. it will not fits in center in potryet mode.or if i increse /decrese pading to make it in center i will not fit in landscap.

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati Use `Fit` instead of `Fill` and try to avoid hard-coded numbers - these may look quite different on different devices. Still use @eakgul's structure